# scrollTop div with margin

Tags: jquery, html, scrolltop

I've got a div that I position almost out of screen by giving it plenty of margin.
It will contain text and users will have to scroll te read it. Don't ask me why I would want to do that, lets just say the background image needs to be visible.

I want the div with text to move up after a certain amount of time.
Animating the scrolltop doesn't seem to work with a div with margin, at least, I can't make it work.

Can any of you guys come up with the solution?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(window).animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, 300);
}, 3000);
```

Here's the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/PaulvdDool/1ctt8xto/

Comment: You want the div to move up, or the window to scroll to top?

Answer (score 0):

That's selector problem
Use:

```
$('body, html')
```

insted of:

```
$(document)
```

Code:

```
console.log("height: " + $(document).height());
setTimeout(function() {
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, 300);
}, 3000);
```

Comment: That is not the problem. The problem is when you try to scroll from top till the total height of the document :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#red').delay(1000).animate({marginTop :'50px'}, 500);
});
```

Also a minor suggestion: try adding `position:fixed` in the css. Change the  `marginTop` value to meet your requirement.